# Python Array Becoming Index Out of Range for the second turn in the loop

Tags: python, sql, arrays, loops

row_norm_hours[col] = row_calculation[0][col]
IndexError: list index out of range

This happens when index = 1 (2nd turn in the loop)
where col = 0, yet I declare the array/list as new.

```
    for index in range(num_rows): #where num_rows is a constant
    ...
    sql_calcultion = "SELECT MonH,TueH,WedH,ThuH,FriH,SatH,SunH,MonOH,TueOH,WedOH,ThuOH,FriOH,SatOH,SunOH FROM Calculation WHERE EmployeeID=" + str(row_employee[index][0]) #EmployeeID
    cursor.execute(sql_calcultion)
    row_calculation = cursor.fetchall() #one row only

    row_norm_hours = {}
    row_ot_hours = {}

    for col in range(7):
        row_norm_hours[col] = row_calculation[0][col]
        row_ot_hours[col] = row_calculation[0][col+7]
```

Any ideas? Thanks

UPDATE: I made a mistake with query, the EmployeeID exists without proper row for Calculation table. Which resulted in the *row_calculation* as being null. Hence *row_calculation[0][col]* for any value of col is an index out of range

Comment: Terminology nitpick: if by "I declare the array/list as new" you are referring to `row_norm_hours`, that's a dict, not an array or list. But your basic premise is correct - indexed assignment to `row_norm_hours` shouldn't fail even when `col` is not yet present in the dict. So the problem must be on the right hand side of the statement.

Comment: Could be because when you do `[col+7]` python it's actually evaluating `col+7` which will result in a non-existent index. Try to assign `col` to another variable. I'm not too sure though

Comment: @HigorRossato row_calculation[0][col+7] is not the line that has the error. Although, i dont think it is the source since row_calculation has 14 rows in total

Comment: @Kevin, upon my testing of 'print(row_calculation)' before, the loop 'for col in range(7)'. It is filled up for index =0 , but NULL when index = 1. You might be right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the query for index=1 returns a non-empty result? Maybe the IndexError comes from the "0" and not the "col" in your code

```
row_norm_hours[col] = row_calculation[0][col]
```

Comment: cursor.fetchall() always returns a 2d array. in the format of data[row][column]. Yet, at some extent you are right about a empty result for index = 1 in row_calculation as a whole. Maybe my mistake is on the query and not the loop.